# Singular homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading a text in algebraic topology and in a proof the following result is used without proof, I tried looking for previous lemmas but it seems that the author either assume the student to know the result or give a proof by himself.

Let $\sigma: I \to X$ and $\tau: I \to X$ be two paths such that $\sigma(1)= \tau(0)$, we define $\sigma \ast \tau$ to be the concatenation of $\sigma$ and $\tau$. The claim is that $\sigma + \tau - \sigma \ast \tau$ is a boundary in $S_1(X)$, i.e in the image $S_2(X) \to S_1(X)$. I don't see if this is trivial enough for the proof to be omitted?

In the above, $X$ denotes a topological space, $I$ denotes the unit interval $[0,1]$ and $S_n(X)$ denotes the free abelian group generated by all continuous maps $\Delta_n \to X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the boundary of the singular 2-simplex which maps the 01 edge to $\sigma$, the 12 edge to $\tau$, and the 02 edge to $\sigma * \tau.$ When you traverse the triangle counterclockwise to compute its boundary, you go against the orientation of the 02 edge (all edges point from lower to higher), so it gets a minus sign.

Let's be more explicit. The singular chain complex is continuous maps from (the geometric realization of) the simplex category to a space $X$, so let's first understand the situation in the simplex category. Here we have the object $[2] = \{0 \to 1\to 2\}.$ There are three obvious face maps $\delta^1\colon[1]\to[2],$ for $i=0,1,2.$

Now a singular 2-simplex is a map $T\colon\Delta^2\to X$ and its boundary is $\partial T=T\circ\delta^0-T\circ\delta^1+T\circ\delta^2.$ So we're looking for a $T$ such that $\partial T = \sigma -\sigma * \tau + \tau.$ Thus we need a singular 2-simplex whose 01 edge ($T\circ\delta^2$) traces $\tau$, whose 12 edge ($T\circ\delta^0$) traces $\sigma$, and whose $02$ edge ($T\circ \delta^1$) traces $\sigma * \tau$. It's a degenerate triangle, with no area, and so no chance of encircling a hole which could prevent the existence of a 2-simplex with this boundary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I must say as I just started studying this I am having a hard time to understand your answer. Would you mind fill is as many details as possible, can you specifically help me understand what edges you are talking about? Sorry but Im really new to this.

Comment: @conrad I added some explanation. is it helpful? Give me an idea which parts you are least familiar with and I can add more

Comment: Very very nice answer, easy to follow, thank you for taking your time. Just one question: how can i see the geometric realization of the 2-simplex? As I understand you consider an element in the 2-simplex as a triangle, can I read about this somewhere?

Comment: i found a nice text of this now. We consider the 2-simplex as a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with vertices (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1). The edges you name 01,02,12, which are those?

Comment: So the object $[2]$ in the simplex category is an abstract directed graph or poset, that is meant to represent a triangle. But if we want to talk about singular chains, we need an honest topological space from which we can consider continuous maps, so the geometric realization is such a space. It's just the standard triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ I guess it doesn't matter where you put the vertices, but maybe a standard place is $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)$.

Comment: @conrad the vertices are labeled $0,1,2$. So the $01$ edge is what I was calling the edge from 0 to 1. But maybe it would be better to call it by the vertex opposite, so the edge from 0 to 1 could be called the 2 edge? Because that's how the coface map is notated in the simplex category. Either way, I hope it's clear now which edges I mean.

Comment: A concrete definition of a singular $2$-sinplex which yields the homology of $\sigma +\tau$ and $\sigma\ast\tau$ is on page 166 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*: Map one edge of the equilateral triangle to $\sigma\ast\tau$ and compose with the orthogonal projection from the triangle to that edge.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map from the boundary of the simplex sending $[e_0,e_1]$ to $X$ via   $\sigma \circ$ (a suitable affine map) and similarly $[e_1,e_2]$ via $\tau \circ$ affine map and $[e_0,e_2]$ via $(\sigma *\tau) \circ$ affine map Where $[e_0,e_1,e_2]$ is the standard $2$-simplex. Then by radial stretching we get a map from $S^1$ to X hence a closed path in X namely, $\sigma * \tau *(\sigma * \tau)^{-1}$ which is nullhomotopic rel $\{0,1\}$ (can be seen using the fundamental groupoid) hence it can be extended to $D^2$ hence by inverse of the radial stretching map from $\Delta^2$ to $D^2$ we get the map $\alpha : \Delta^2 \rightarrow X$. Then the boundary of $\alpha$ is the required element of $S_1(X)$.